# Помогите, разместить блоки как на макете

Tags: html, css

```css
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
p,
a {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: normal;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.principle {
  color: #000;
}

.d1 {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #6d163d;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://allfont.ru/allfont.css?fonts=arial-narrow-bold" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title>Свила</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <div class="principle">
      <h2>Принципы</h2>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="d1"></div>
        <h3>Гибкость в решение бизннес-задач</h3>
        <p>Мы открыто обсуждаем варианты <br> организации мероприятия и подбираем<br> свое решение для каждого случая </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="d1"></div>
      <h3>Мы собрали команду из лучших</h3>
      <p>МГлубокий опыт в кейтеринге и энергичный <br>настрой команды позволят легко добиться<br> целей мероприятия </p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="d1"></div>
      <h3>Заботимся о своих клиентах</h3>
      <p>Находимся на связи с клиентом 24/7,<br> чтобы напрямую услышать потребности
        <br>и приоритетно решить задачи </p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="d1"></div>
      <h3>Гарантируем лучшие цены</h3>
      <p>Конкурентноспособные цены на меню и <br>условия оплаты для развития
        <br> долгосрочных партнерских отношений </p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="d1"></div>
      <h3>Каждое событие уникально</h3>
      <p>Душевный подход к организации
        <br>кейтеринга создаст нужную атмосферу и <br>сделать событие особенным</p>
    </div>





  </main>


</body>

</html>
```

[image: Макет]

Comment: Не ответ на вопрос, но — Bootstrap/Foundation Вы по какой-то причине игнорируете?

Comment: я с ним еще не работала, пока учусь, просто для себя

Comment: получается, что блоки item)

Comment: @Sevastopol' а как бы вы тогда разместили?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  align-item: center;
}
.circle{
  margin-left: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.circle:before{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: -50px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #6D163D;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

span{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
 <div class='circle'>
    <span>Мы открыто обсуждаем варианты</span>
    организации мероприятия и подбираем
    свое решение для каждого случая
 </div>
  <div class='circle'>
    <span>Мы открыто обсуждаем варианты</span>
    организации мероприятия и подбираем
    свое решение для каждого случая
 </div>
  <div class='circle'>
    <span>Мы открыто обсуждаем варианты</span>
    организации мероприятия и подбираем
    свое решение для каждого случая
 </div>
  <div class='circle'>
    <span>Мы открыто обсуждаем варианты</span>
    организации мероприятия и подбираем
    свое решение для каждого случая
 </div>
  <div class='circle'>
    <span>Мы открыто обсуждаем варианты</span>
    организации мероприятия и подбираем
    свое решение для каждого случая
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Для блоков `.item` в этом случае нужно задать свойство `display: inline-block;`

```css
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
p,
a {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: normal;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.principle {
  max-width: 800px;
  color: #000;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: top;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}

.d1 {
  float: left;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #6d163d;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: -35px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 0 40px 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://allfont.ru/allfont.css?fonts=arial-narrow-bold" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title>Свила</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <h2>Принципы</h2>
    <div class="principle">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="d1"></div>
        <h3>Гибкость в решение бизннес-задач</h3>
        <p>Мы открыто обсуждаем варианты <br> организации мероприятия и подбираем<br> свое решение для каждого случая </p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="d1"></div>
        <h3>Мы собрали команду из лучших</h3>
        <p>МГлубокий опыт в кейтеринге и энергичный <br>настрой команды позволят легко добиться<br> целей мероприятия </p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="d1"></div>
        <h3>Заботимся о своих клиентах</h3>
        <p>Находимся на связи с клиентом 24/7,<br> чтобы напрямую услышать потребности
          <br>и приоритетно решить задачи </p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="d1"></div>
        <h3>Гарантируем лучшие цены</h3>
        <p>Конкурентноспособные цены на меню и <br>условия оплаты для развития
          <br> долгосрочных партнерских отношений </p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="d1"></div>
        <h3>Каждое событие уникально</h3>
        <p>Душевный подход к организации
          <br>кейтеринга создаст нужную атмосферу и <br>сделать событие особенным</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```